# How to add embedded hyperlinks in a Monday.com form?

Tags: links, crm, monday.com

I'm currently developing a form on Monday.com and have encountered a limitation that I'm hoping to find a workaround for. The core of the issue is that I need to include embedded hyperlinks within the text of my form's descriptions. The standard functionality of Monday.com forms seems to only allow for plain text in these areas, without the ability to hyperlink specific words or phrases.

To clarify, I'm not looking to include full URLs in the description that users can click or copy and paste into their browsers. Instead, I want certain words within the description text to be clickable hyperlinks. For example, if the description mentions "Click here for more information," I'd like "here" to be a clickable link that takes the user to a specified URL.

As of now, I've been including the full URLs in the description sections, but this approach lacks the polish and user-friendliness that embedded hyperlinks would provide.

What I've tried so far:

- I've searched through Monday.com's documentation and forums for any built-in features or workarounds that might allow for embedded hyperlinks within form descriptions but haven't found anything applicable.

My question to the community:

- Are there any known workarounds or third-party tools that integrate well with Monday.com for achieving this?
- Has anyone successfully implemented embedded hyperlinks in Monday.com forms, and if so, how did you accomplish it?

I appreciate any guidance, insights, or suggestions the community can provide. Thank you in advance for your help!